# Custom Bottom Navigation Bar Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to recreate this effect in Flutter, I initially created it in Angular using CSS.

Basically imagine a bottom NavBar sitting behind a container with bottom border radius.

I'm pretty new to Flutter and still learning things, but there doesn't seem to be an obvious way to accomplish this. I do know about Stack but I'm not sure if I can combine it with BottomNavigationBar (or if it's good practice seeing how a property on Scaffold is made specifically for it)

[image: NavBar]

Here's what I tried using ClipPath.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        extendBody: true,
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
                child: Container(
              height: 100,
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.red,
              ),
            ))
          ],
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: const NavBar(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const NavBar({super.key});
  @override
  State<NavBar> createState() => _NavBarState();
}

class _NavBarState extends State<NavBar> {
  static const List<BottomNavigationBarItem> _items = <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
      label: 'Home',
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.search),
      label: 'Search',
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.messenger_outline),
      label: 'Message',
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.person_outlined),
      label: 'Profile',
    ),
  ];
  final int _selectedIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipPath(
      clipper: CustomShapeClipper(),
      child: SizedBox(
        height: 75,
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          items: _items,
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
          showUnselectedLabels: true,
          showSelectedLabels: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CustomShapeClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    final path = Path();
    double cornerHeight = size.height - 75;
    path.moveTo(0, size.height);
    path.lineTo(0, cornerHeight); // Raise the starting point of the curve to the top right corner
    path.quadraticBezierTo(size.width * 0.5, size.height - 50, size.width, cornerHeight); // Adjust the control points to flatten the curve
    path.lineTo(size.width, size.height);
    path.close();

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

This is what it looks like:

[image: Code Example Output]

Is there a better way to accomplish this?
Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: So the issue is that your Bottom section needs to have a corner radius is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `CustomPainter`

**fixed code**:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        extendBody: true,
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                height: 100,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: const NavBar(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const NavBar({super.key});
  @override
  State<NavBar> createState() => _NavBarState();
}

class _NavBarState extends State<NavBar> {
  static const List<BottomNavigationBarItem> _items = <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined),
      label: 'Home',
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.search),
      label: 'Search',
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.messenger_outline),
      label: 'Message',
    ),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(
      icon: Icon(Icons.person_outlined),
      label: 'Profile',
    ),
  ];
  final int _selectedIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomPaint(
      painter: _Painter(radius: const Radius.elliptical(100, 75)),
      child: SizedBox(
        child: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          items: _items,
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
          showUnselectedLabels: true,
          showSelectedLabels: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _Painter extends CustomPainter {
  final Radius radius;

  _Painter({this.radius = Radius.zero});

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.white
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill;

    final width = size.width;
    final height = size.height;
    final yRadius = radius.y;
    final xRadius = radius.x;
    final p1 = Offset(0, -yRadius);
    final p2 = Offset(xRadius, 0);
    final p3 = Offset(width - xRadius, 0);
    final p4 = Offset(width, -yRadius);
    final p5 = Offset(width, height);
    final p6 = Offset(0, height);

    final path = Path();
    path.moveTo(p1.dx, p1.dy);
    path.arcToPoint(p2, radius: radius, clockwise: false);
    path.lineTo(p3.dx, p3.dy);
    path.arcToPoint(p4, radius: radius, clockwise: false);
    path.lineTo(p5.dx, p5.dy);
    path.lineTo(p6.dx, p6.dy);
    path.close();

    canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant _Painter oldDelegate) {
    return oldDelegate.radius != radius;
  }
}
```

**result**:
[image]

Comment: Thanks! This works great, I'm just wondering which approach would be better. This or the one below by @adan. 

One advantage I see here is that it allows for the reusablity of the navbar amongst all pages. Where adan's solution I would have to clip the body of all custom pages I create.  

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: If the tab screens in your application are different - use the method from `@adan`
If the tab screens are the same - use my approach, following the `DRY` (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle.

Answer (score 2):

The simple approach is you can use `ClipRRect` to clip your body, and by using this method you can change the radius easily by changing `borderRadius` property.

The code below is to demonstrate the clipping result with `ClipRRect` to `ListView`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(50)),
                child: Container(
                    height: 100,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.red),
                    child: ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: 100,
                      itemBuilder: (_, i) => Text(i.toString()),
                    )),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: const NavBar(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class NavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  const NavBar({super.key});
  @override
  State<NavBar> createState() => _NavBarState();
}

class _NavBarState extends State<NavBar> {
  static const List<BottomNavigationBarItem> _items = <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
    BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.home_outlined), label: 'Home'),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.search), label: 'Search'),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.messenger_outline), label: 'Message'),
    BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.person_outlined), label: 'Profile'),
  ];
  final int _selectedIndex = 0;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BottomNavigationBar(
      type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
      elevation: 0,
      items: _items,
      currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
      selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
      unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
      showUnselectedLabels: true,
      showSelectedLabels: true,
    );
  }
}
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Hopefully it can solve your problem, Thanks